# Ошибка: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termgame'"

Tags: python, импорт, модули

Я написал тесты для библиотеки `termgame`.

Структура проекта:

```
 TermGame  # Здесь я нахожусь при запуске тестов
  ...
   termgame
    ...
   tests
     main.py
     test_clock.py
    ...
```

Когда пытаюсь запустить их командой:

```sh
python3.10 tests/main.py
```

выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/e/nick/Python/TermGame/tests/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test_clock import ClockTestCase                        
  File "/mnt/e/nick/Python/TermGame/tests/test_clock.py", line 2, in <module>
    import termgame as tg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termgame'
```

Если нужно, вот кода.

`tests/main.py`:

```py
from test_clock import ClockTestCase
from test_color import ColorTestCase
from test_draw import DrawTestCase
from test_events import EventsTestCase
from test_font import FontTestCase
from test_image import ImageTestCase
from test_screen import ScreenTestCase

import unittest

unittest.main()
```

`tests/test_clock.py`:

```py
import termgame as tg

import time
import unittest


class ClockTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testing_clock = tg.Clock()

    def test_tick(self):
        start = time.time()
        for _ in range(30):
            self.testing_clock.tick(30)
        finish = time.time()
        self.assertEqual(round(finish - start), 1)

    def test_get_fps(self):
        self.testing_clock.tick(30)
        self.assertEqual(self.testing_clock.get_fps(), 30.0)
```

Надеюсь все понятно, если нет пишите в комментариях.

Comment: Текущая директория, откуда изначально запускается скрипт, не добавляется в PYTHONPATH, только директория запускаемого скрипта (в данном случае tests). Как вариант, можно добавить минимальный setup.py (либо pyproject.toml), установить пакет в виртуальное окружение через `pip install -e .`, потом из этого же виртуального окружения запускать тесты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае только так.

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "../termgame") # две точки означает подняться выше.
                                  # То есть как в проводнике кнопкой назад одно нажатие
import termgame
```

Вам вообще-то нужно почитать про иеархию поиска модулей или (sys.path в поисковик введите), посмотрите как допустим PyCharm делает проект.

Comment: Я вставил этот код в `tests/main.py` и всё сработало.

Comment: Ну так будет работать но структура не правильная. посмотрите как это делается в стандартных либах.